# Edges don't show in a graph using Networkx - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

I am plotting a directed graph in python using networkx and matplotlib. However, not all edges are visible. The nodes are so close to each other that it doesn't show a path between two nodes.

Code:

```
import networkx as nx

resultNodes = ['P0', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'P7', 'P8', 'P9']

resultEdges = [('P0', 'P4'), ('P0', 'P2'), ('P0', 'P1'), ('P1', 'P7'), ('P1', 'P8'),
               ('P1', 'P2'), ('P2', 'P3'), ('P4', 'P5'), ('P4', 'P6'), ('P5', 'P6'),
               ('P9', 'P2'), ('P9', 'P7'), ('P9', 'P1')]

G=nx.DiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from(resultNodes)
G.add_edges_from(resultEdges)

print("Nodes of graph: ")
print(G.nodes())
print("Edges of graph: ")
print(G.edges())

nx.draw(G,with_labels=True,font_size=15,node_color='yellowgreen',node_size=1000)
```

[image: Output image shows no edge between P4,P5,P6 as those nodes are so close]

Comment: What are `resultNodes` and `resultEdges`?  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't add that to the comments, add to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the positions of the nodes, and pass to the draw function. See [the doc](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout).

Example:

```
pos = nx.drawing.layout.circular_layout(G)

nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, font_size=15,
        node_color='yellowgreen', node_size=1000)
```

[image: circular_layout]